# Delete after 45 days

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

If an account kept inactive for 45 days that account should be deleted automatically. How to perform this? Do the following function

old_date+45 delete

Or is there any other logic for it?

required in : MySQL, ASP.NET/C#

Comment: No clear why did you mentioned ASP .NET, when do you want to apply the deletion logic? Exactly 45 days after? Check daily and delete old accounts?

Comment: To check daily I am talking about a large database not to handle 2/3 records....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 45 DAY);
```

Comment: Do ODBC command too uses same syntax? And what's it in came of minutes?